# Select from tag type - input dropdown with selenium C# webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

[image: Dropdwon]

How can i get element from below dropdwon, i have used Select command to select dropdowns, but here type is input.

```
<input class="tp-select-input" autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" data-testid="register-country" value="">
```

Comment: Did you try to locate it as common WebElement by CSS/XPath?

Comment: Need some more info on HTML. Like is there any arrow symbol clicking on which your drop down options are visible ? What are the options to select from dropdown ?

Comment: i have tried with this:
SelectElement oSelect = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("tp-select-input")))

Comment: Mate i can not help with images, you need to share HTML source . However I am giving logic in Answer section. Please  implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dropdown you want to select value from is not a select type tag, Selenium Select method wont work on it. You have to follow below steps:

1. Click on Dropdown / or Arrow
2. Locate webelement you want to select from dropdown
3. Use java script executioner to click the option you want to select

Since you have not given complete HTML, below is the dummy code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@data-testid='register-country']")).Click() // Click on dropdown
 IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
 executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[text()='Austria']"))); //You can give more accurate xpath for country you want to select based on other HTML attributes
```

Comment: @Kishan Rathod- why did you un-accept my answer after accepting it in first place ?? Didn’t it solve your problem???

Comment: Sorry Rahul, I did not unacccept your answer but may be I did also accept other answer and your answer automatically unacccept, I accept it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with below code

`IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("tp-select-input")); driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text()='Australia']")); element.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Down); element.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Return);`